# How to get the difference of elements inside a list of lists in Java?

Tags: java, list

My actual problem is similar to this. I have two boxes, which contains some colorful baskets. Each of these baskets contains some fruits in multiple quantity.

Below is the pictorial representation of such scenario-

```
Box1
Red Basket = [(Mango, 12), (Apple, 7)]
Yellow Basket = [(Apple, 7), (Banana, 2)]
Blue Basket = [(Orange, 16)]

Box2
Red Basket = [(Mango, 8), (Apple, 10), (Papaya, 1)]
Yellow Basket = [(Apple, 10), (Orange, 10)]
```

Now I wanna do is to calculate the difference of each fruit, keeping in mind that difference can be calculated only on same color of baskets. Below is what, the difference should show me-

```
Difference Box
Red Basket = [(Mango, 4), (Apple, 3), (Papaya, 1)]
Yellow Basket = [(Apple, 3), (Banana, 8)]
Blue Basket = [(Orange, 16)]
```

My Java classes looks like following-

Main Class:

```
public class Difference {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit mango1 = new Fruit("Mango", 12);
        Fruit apple1 = new Fruit("Apple", 7);
        Fruit orange1 = new Fruit("Orange", 16);
        Fruit banana1 = new Fruit("Banana", 2);

        Bucket redBucket1 = new Bucket("Red");
        Bucket yellowBucket1 = new Bucket("Yellow");
        Bucket blueBucket1 = new Bucket("Blue");

        redBucket1.addFruit(mango1);
        redBucket1.addFruit(apple1);

        yellowBucket1.addFruit(apple1);
        yellowBucket1.addFruit(banana1);

        blueBucket1.addFruit(orange1);

        Box box1 = new Box();
        box1.addBucket(redBucket1);
        box1.addBucket(yellowBucket1);
        box1.addBucket(blueBucket1);

        Fruit mango2 = new Fruit("Mango", 8);
        Fruit apple2 = new Fruit("Apple", 10);
        Fruit orange2 = new Fruit("Orange", 10);
        Fruit papaya2 = new Fruit("Papaya", 1);

        Bucket redBucket2 = new Bucket("Red");

        Bucket yellowBucket2 = new Bucket("Yellow");

        redBucket2.addFruit(mango2);
        redBucket2.addFruit(apple2);
        redBucket2.addFruit(papaya2);

        yellowBucket2.addFruit(apple2);
        yellowBucket2.addFruit(orange2);

        Box box2 = new Box();
        box2.addBucket(redBucket2);
        box2.addBucket(yellowBucket2);

        Box difference = getDifference(box1, box2);
    }

    private static Box getDifference(Box box1, Box box2) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Extra Classes:

```
public class Fruit {
    private int count;
    private String name;
    public Fruit(String name, int count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
}

public class Bucket {
    private List<Fruit> fruits;
    private String color;
    public Bucket(String color) {
        fruits= new ArrayList<Fruit>();
        this.color = color;
    }
}

public class Box {
    private List<Bucket> buckets;
    public Box() {
        buckets= new ArrayList<Bucket>();
    }
    public void addBucket(Bucket bucket) {
        buckets.add(bucket);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this kind of difference? I tried it but my solution is ugly, where for each element I am traversing entire list.

Comment: Is this a deliberate class design / choice? If not then you should rework it as there are slightly better data structures available for this task (Hint: Map, Set).

Comment: Your difference method should be on the `Box` which can then call another difference method on each `Bucket`. This should then be trivial.

Comment: Looking at the difference box, shouldn't the Yellow basket in the box2 actually be `Yellow Basket = [(Apple, 10), (Banana, 10)]`?

Comment: Shouldn't the difference box yellow basket banana = 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to create the class `Basket`. It's a real world notion, so it seems a good design choice at first sight.

```
public class Basket {
    private Color color;                   // Color is an enum
    private Map<Fruit, Integer> fruitMap   // map of pairs: <fruit kind, number of fruit of that kind>

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the baskets containing a list of fruit, try using a hashmap.  A Hasmap will allow you to get each fruit by the key used, probably the fruit name VS iterating over the entire list.